# Limit points of $\left\{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{5^p}\ : \ m,n,p\in\mathbb N\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I intend to find the limit points of the set $\mathcal S = \left\{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{5^p}\ : \ m,n,p\in\mathbb N\right\}$.

These are the ones I could think of:

- $S_1 = \left\{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{3^n}\ : \ m,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$
- $S_2 = \left\{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{5^p}\ : \ m,p\in\mathbb N\right\}$
- $S_3 = \left\{\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{5^p}\ : \ n,p\in\mathbb N\right\}$
- $S_4 = \left\{\frac{1}{k^n}\ : \ n\in\mathbb N, \ k\in\{2,3,5\}\right\}$
- $S_5=\{0\}$

So the derived set of $\mathcal S$ is $\bigcup\limits_i S_i$.

Am I missing anything or that's it? In an exam setting, how do I write this more formally i.e., show that there are no limit points other than these?

Another question, is the set $\mathcal S\cup\{0\}$ closed in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Let $$a_{m,n,k}=2^{-n}+3^{-m}+5^{-k}.$$ If you have a sequence $(a_{{m_\ell}, {n_\ell}, {k_\ell}})_{\ell\in \mathbb{N}}$ and all the triples indices are pairwise distinct, then $(m_\ell)_\ell$ or $(n_\ell)_\ell$ or $(k_\ell)_\ell$ are unbounded (logical or). Then you correctly considered all the cases where one of coordinates of triple goes to infinity (this gives all the limit points you suggested), if you wish to be precise, you want to give an actual sequence converging to those candidates of limit points. Then you need to prove that you cannot get more than those limit points.

Comment: @TonyK Is it? While posting, I had in mind that $0\not\in \mathcal S$ but $\inf S=0$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right. And this kind of question has an easy generalization  to a finite sum of similar fractions.

Comment: Whoops, you are right. I was confusing $\mathcal S$ with its limit points.